# How to modify a file by using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

```
awk '/<ul>/ {ul++} ul == 6 { getline } 1' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/test.html
```

if i run this line of code, the shell will not help me to modify the file, instead, it only output the result in the shell. Can any one help???thx

Comment: you could use `sed` to modify the file...

Comment: @sdolgy: No, not in this case. `sed` is not able to do the kind of editing he wants to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just send the output to a file; you might want to copy the file beforehand so you don't have to overwrite the file you're reading (which might otherwise lead to undesired behavior).

```
cp test.html test.html.orig
awk 'your awk script here' test.html.orig >test.html
# and then optionally remove the copy:
rm test.html.orig
```

Comment: +1 however, in order to keep the original file in place for the maximum time (in case others need to read it): `awk '...' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`

Comment: @glenn jackman: You're right; but the downside of your method is that it doesn't leave a copy of the original file in case things go wrong. If you want both, you can of course write to a temporary file, then copy the original file to a backup file, and *then* move the temporary file to the original one.

Comment: The assumption is that is something goes wrong in the awk process, it will exit with a non-zero status and the "mv" will not run.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of, the awk script itself containing a bug that causes it to output the wrong thing, without error.

Comment: @glennjackman 's method works well, regardless of hypothetical edge-cases.